# Swift SpriteKit Nodeのタッチ検出方法

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

Nodeをタッチした際に動作させたいアクションがあるのですが、Nodeのタッチを検出致しません。
情報不足ございましたらお申し付けください。

【実現したい事】
class WorldNodeでは画面をスクロール動作する為のコードを記載しています。
class GameScene内のtouchesEndedでclass WorldNodeのcontentNodeをタッチした際に、class GameScene内のメソッドを動作させたいです。
逆にclass WorldNode内のtouchesEndedでclass GameSceneのメソッドを動作させる方法でも良いかなと思ってます。

・タッチしたいNode：class WorldNodeのcontentNode

```
var viewSizeWidth: Int = 375
var viewSizeHeight: Int = 812

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var battleship: SKSpriteNode!

    let worldNode =  WorldNode(size: CGSize(width: viewSizeWidth * 8, height: viewSizeHeight * 8))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(worldNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       let touch = touches.first
       let location = touch!.location(in: self)
//ここにclass WorldNode内のcontentNodeをタッチした際、class GameScene内のメソッドを動作させたい
    }

//このメソッドをタッチイベントで使用したい。
    func addBattleship() {
        let battleship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "battleship")
        self.battleship = battleship
        battleship.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        battleship.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        battleship.zPosition = 2.0
        self.worldNode.contentNode.addChild(battleship)
        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: 2700, duration: 10)
        battleship.run(move)
    }

}

//WorldNodeでは、画面をtouchesMovedでスクロールする為のコードを書いています。
class WorldNode: SKSpriteNode {

    var contentNode = SKNode()

    private var startX: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var lastX: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var startY: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var lastY: CGFloat = 0.0

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: SKColor.gray, size: size)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.contentNode.name = "contentNode"
        let ConstraintYRange = SKRange (lowerLimit: self.frame.minY + 500, upperLimit: self.frame.maxY - 500)
        let ConstraintXRange = SKRange (lowerLimit: self.frame.minX + self.frame.maxX / 2, upperLimit: self.frame.maxX - self.frame.maxX / 2)
        let yconst = SKConstraint.positionY(ConstraintYRange)
        let xconst = SKConstraint.positionX(ConstraintXRange)
        contentNode.constraints = [yconst, xconst]
        self.addChild(contentNode)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            let touch = touches.first
            let location = touch!.location(in: self)
            startX = location.x
            lastX = location.x
            startY = location.y
            lastY = location.y
        }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch!.location(in: self)
//ここにclass GameSceneのメソッドを動作させてもOK？（GameSceneのメソッドを引っ張る方法分かりません）
}

        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
            let location =  touch.location(in: self)

            let currentX = location.x
            let currentY = location.y

            let scrollspeed: CGFloat = 1.0
            let newX = self.contentNode.position.x + ((currentX - lastX) * scrollspeed)
            let newY = self.contentNode.position.y + ((currentY - lastY) * scrollspeed)

            let limitFactir: CGFloat = 100
            let leftLimitX = self.size.width * (-limitFactir)
            let rightLimitX = self.size.width * limitFactir
            let lowLimitY = self.size.height * (-limitFactir)
            let heightLimitY = self.size.height * limitFactir

            if newX < leftLimitX && newY < lowLimitY {
                self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: leftLimitX, y: self.contentNode.position.y)
                self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.contentNode.position.x, y: lowLimitY)
            } else if newX > rightLimitX && newY > heightLimitY {
                self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: rightLimitX, y: contentNode.position.y)
                self.contentNode.position  = CGPoint(x: self.contentNode.position.y, y: heightLimitY)
            } else {
                self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: newX, y: self.contentNode.position.y)
                self.contentNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.contentNode.position.x, y: newY)
            }


            lastX = currentX
            lastY = currentY

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、ですが、期待どおり動かない原因は、次の行、クラス`WorldNode`のイニシアライザ内、

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true
```

です。この行を削除するだけで、期待どおりの結果になる可能性は高いでしょう。

---

`SKNode`のプロパティ`isUserInteractionEnabled`は、いったいなんなのか？それはXcodeのドキュメントにあたって、しっかり把握するべきです。

[Instance Property - isUserInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483109-isuserinteractionenabled)

このページに、**Important**とタイトルがあるコラムがあります。重要といっているのですから、無視せずに、必ず目を通して、なにが書いてあるか理解してください。

> **Important**
>   In addition to setting isUserInteractionEnabled to true, you
>   must subclass the node and define event callbacks in order to respond
>   to user input.

このプロパティ（`isUserInteractionEnabled`）を`true`にするなら、ユーザの入力（画面タッチ）に対するイベント処理を必ず定義しなければいけない。そういう意味のことが書かれています。
なお、Xcodeのドキュメントでは、いささか表現が婉曲になる傾向が見られます。「may be」は、「やってもいいかも」くらいのレベルで受け取られがちですが、Xcodeのドキュメントでは「やったほうがいいでしょ」のレベルで使われます。同様に「should」は、「するべき」でなく「しなければいけない」と理解するべきですし、まして「must」と言われたら、「やらないと厄災がふりかかるぞ」という最高級の強制の意味となります。
ご提示のコードに沿って説明すると、クラス`WorldNode`のプロパティ`isUserInteractionEnabled`は、イニシアライザで`true`になるので、クラス定義の中に、`touchesBegan`、`touchesEnded`などの、ユーザの画面タッチイベントを受け取って、処理するメソッドを定義しなければいけないのですが、実際は定義されていません。そのため、ユーザの画面タッチのイベントは、なんの対処もされることなく、かつ`WorldNode`のインスタンスの段階でイベントに対する処理が完了したとみなされ、そこでイベントが消滅します。よって、クラス`GameScene`のイベント処理メソッド`touchesBegan`は、実行されることはありません。（インスタンス`worldNode`以外の場所をタッチすれば、実行されます）。

Comment: @nagonsoftwareさん
丁寧なご回答誠にありがとうございます。Xcodeドキュメントの理解の必要性を感じました。
質問内容が凡そ不完全でありました。ご質問が分かりにくくならぬ様、本来のコードを簡潔にまとめたつもりだったのですが、それにより私の意図するご質問ができていない様に感じました。
元のコードではWorldNode内にタッチイベントの記載をしていたのですが、それでも期待する動作が敵わず、、
二度手間で大変恐縮ですが、ご質問内容を編集し、より質問内容を明確化致しますので、ご回答いただけますと幸いでございます。

Comment: 私は、この回答をするため、自身の個人的な時間を割り当てています。言い換えると、仕事で回答をしているのではありません。キーボードを叩いて文章を打ち込むのに、30分もかけてはいませんが、プロパティ`isUserInteractionEnabled`の挙動を確認するための検証プログラムを書いて、実行してみるなどの時間まで入れると、2時間を超える時間を、この回答のためにかけています。なので、質問の内容が変わったからといって、全てなかったことにすることはありません。ご質問を新規に立てていただければ、回答する用意はありますが、これ以上回答に手を加えることはありません。あしからず。

Comment: @nagonsoftwareさん
無神経な発言、申し訳ございませんでした。
私の思考が及ばないばかりに失礼な発言をしてしまいました。
今回のisUserInteractionEnabledに関する解釈について、大変勉強になりました。
今回ご質問させて頂いた内容に関してのご回答は頂いた内容にて解決されるものと存ますので、解決とさせて頂き、ご指摘の通り、また改めて別のご質問という形で投稿させて頂きます。
この度は最後までご丁寧にありがとうございました。